# " ionic build android " giving ANDROID_HOME error

Tags: android, linux, cordova, ionic-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I get the following error

```
$ ionic build android
Running command: /home/dna/myApp1/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/dna/myApp1
add to body class: platform-android
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

After referring a previous question, I added the following to .bashrc file, without any success in solving the issue

> 1.export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/SDK
>
> 2.export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin

Kindly assist

Comment: remove the second line and try again.

Comment: @PrashantGhimire , I tried with only first line. But the same error repeated. What to do ? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to add platforms-tools and tools like this : 
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Comment: @RémiP , as a single line ? In .bashrc ? Thanks

Comment: @RémiP , I added the line you gave as single to .bashrc . Got the same error though.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved by adding the following line at the bottom of .profile ( a hidden file in home folder )

PATH="$PATH:/home/YourUsrName/Android/Sdk/tools"

make sure to change YourUsrName to your user name.